# Where can I find the previous years' International Astronomy Olympiad question papers?

Tags: astrophysics

I have looked at the [official site](http://www.issp.ac.ru/iao/) but the link for previous papers isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A blog called [Science Olympiad Blog](https://scienceolympiadsbd.blogspot.com/2014/10/iao-problems-2011-2014.html) claims to have the problem sheets for 2011-2014.